# My desktop application won't run on a Windows 8 machine

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Express on Windows 7 to build a desktop application using .NET services with DirectX 11. I've started testing on 2 different Windows 8 machines. One also has VS2013E on it, and uses Windows 8 Pro. The other does not have Visual Studio, and uses Windows 8.1. On the first machine, all I had to do was move my executable onto the machine and it worked fine. On the second, I see no evidence that it attempts to run. In fact, I added a MessageBox.Show(...) as the very first line in my code to see if my code was breaking anywhere, but still, nothing happens. Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Comment: Any messages in the application event log? Does your process show up in the taskmanager?

Comment: It is not appearing in the task manager. One of my IT team's guys ran WinDbg on it, and it's giving a series of C++ EH Exceptions. My code is all C# (using SlimDX  for the DirectX). I'm guessing there's a problem with trying to run DirectX, although DxDiag says it is using DirectX 11.

Comment: It's also saying there's a "FileNotFound" exception. I really have no idea what it could be referring to, given that it won't even run the first line of code.

Comment: It likely that it's missing one of the c runtimes.  Use the app called "Depends" to detemine what dlls are missing.  You can also try Process Monitor to see what DLLs aren't found.